# First official sport with timer stopage

Tags: rules, trivia

What was the first ever team sport to stop the timer during a match and only count actual game time? (for example the NBA or the NFL)

Comment: "NBA" is not a sport, it is a sports competition. If you mean "basketball" instead, the answer will be very different.

Comment: Surely Chess, some 300 years ago.

Comment: @Chenmunka OP noted "team sport" not individual. While team chess does exist, it is not as obvious an answer due to the time frame in which team chess has developed which is far more recent than the game of chess itself.